# Set up backup from private Ethereum (Ganache)

Tags: truffle, private-blockchain, truffle-migration, truffle-contract, ganache

I have created an ethereum application with Ganache and truffle js. i have installed ganache in a server, and th application work. but when i stop the server i lose the the smart contract that i have deployed. How can i set up a backup in case de cut of the server. i have tested

ganche-cli --db /path/

i can recoup my balnces one time and i can't done a transactions any more . 
how can i set up a backup

Answer (score 0):

When starting **ganache-cli**, you can specify the flag `--db /path/to/db` which creates the DB directory if it doesn't exist and save the blockchain state. So when you restart ganache with the same flag, it initializes the blockchain from this state.

```
ganache-cli --db /path/to/db/
```

Extract from [documentation](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli):

> --db: Specify a path to a directory to save the chain database. If a database already exists, ganache-cli will initialize that chain
>   instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Sorry didn't get that. `--db` stores the entire blockchain states (transactions, accounts balances, smart contract states, etc...)